# Finding smallest and biggest value in NSArray of NSNumbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

What's an effective and great way to compare all the values of `NSArray` that contains `NSNumbers` from `floats` to find the biggest one and the smallest one?

Any ideas how to do this nice and quick in Objective-C?

Comment: There is no such thing as an NSArray that contains floats. It would have to be an NSArray that contains NSNumbers.

Comment: @matt Thanks! I've corrected the question name

Answer (score 147, accepted):

If *execution speed* (not *programming speed*) is important, then an explicit loop is the fastest. I made the following tests with an array of 1000000 random numbers:

Version 1: sort the array:

```
NSArray *sorted1 = [numbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
// 1.585 seconds
```

Version 2: Key-value coding, using "doubleValue":

```
NSNumber *max=[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"];
NSNumber *min=[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@min.doubleValue"];
// 0.778 seconds
```

Version 3: Key-value coding, using "self":

```
NSNumber *max=[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
NSNumber *min=[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"];
// 0.390 seconds
```

Version 4: Explicit loop:

```
float xmax = -MAXFLOAT;
float xmin = MAXFLOAT;
for (NSNumber *num in numbers) {
    float x = num.floatValue;
    if (x < xmin) xmin = x;
    if (x > xmax) xmax = x;
}
// 0.019 seconds
```

Version 5: Block enumeration:

```
__block float xmax = -MAXFLOAT;
__block float xmin = MAXFLOAT;
[numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *num, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    float x = num.floatValue;
    if (x < xmin) xmin = x;
    if (x > xmax) xmax = x;
}];
// 0.024 seconds
```

The test program creates an array of 1000000 random numbers and then applies all sorting
techniques to the same array. The timings above are the output of one run, but I make about 20 runs with very similar results in each run. I also changed the order in which the 5 sorting methods are applied to exclude caching effects.

**Update:** I have now created a (hopefully) better test program. The full source code is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5356982. The average times for sorting an
array of 1000000 random numbers are (in seconds, on an 3.1 GHz Core i5 iMac, release compile):

```
Sorting      1.404
KVO1         1.087
KVO2         0.367
Fast enum    0.017
Block enum   0.021
```

**Update 2:** As one can see, fast enumeration is faster than block enumeration (which is also stated here: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/2337-incremental-arrayification/).

**EDIT:** The following is *completely wrong*, because I forgot to initialize the object used as lock, as Hot Licks correctly noticed, so that no synchronization is done at all.
And with `lock = [[NSObject alloc] init];` the concurrent enumeration is *so slow*
that I dare not to show the result. Perhaps a faster synchronization mechanism might
help ...)

<strike>This changes dramatically if you add the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option to the
block enumeration:</strike>

```
__block float xmax = -MAXFLOAT;
__block float xmin = MAXFLOAT;
id lock;
[numbers enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSNumber *num, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    float x = num.floatValue;
    @synchronized(lock) {
        if (x < xmin) xmin = x;
        if (x > xmax) xmax = x;
    }
}];
```

The timing here is

```
Concurrent enum  0.009
```

so it is about twice as fast as fast enumeration. The result is probably not representative
because it depends on the number of threads available. But interesting anyway! Note that I
have used the "easiest-to-use" synchronization method, which might not be the fastest.

Comment: often block enumeration is faster than fast enumeration. did u try that? how often did u execute your examples?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I have updated the answer. Block enumeration is slower than fast enumeration here.

Comment: How often did u execute the codes? one or few runs wont give you a good result.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I will improve the test program to determine the average execution time for each method, and then report the result later.

Comment: @MartinR, I tested it with sorting a randomized array of 1000000 100 times. fast enum: 2.309 sec, block enum: 2.266

Comment: @MartinR, I repeated that test 30 times, block enumeration was faster each time.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I don't understand your code. Where is the block enumeration? I see 2 (identical) fast enumerations.

Comment: damn, i wrote it into another project and that factored it out to a new one. I guess it was a c&p error. give me a second to recreate it.

Comment: @MartinR: i fixed my program. and now fast is idead faster, contrary to bbum's explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4487012/106435

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Yes, that is also my result. See also http://blog.bignerdranch.com/2337-incremental-arrayification/: *"In general, fast enumeration is the winner in both performance and readability"*.

Comment: @MartinR: one of the comments over there suggests that it is the usage of the `__block` qualifier, that slows the block enumeration dramatically. So with changing properties on the enumerated object it could still be as fast (faster ??) as fast enumeration, and my faith in bbum is restored.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I tried this (pointers) and noticed almost no difference (0.020 instead of 0.021). But concurrent enumeration is (of course) faster, see "Update 2" above.

Comment: I have a downvote in the very same moment. and @ate50eggs did down vote two times today. so the reason is: Revenge. He must assume one of us downvoted him.

Comment: caching would be faster still ... would have to mark as dirty if min or max were removed... and be very type careful with floats and doubles etc.

Comment: I confess to being a little surprised that concurrent really is about twice as fast as single threaded, even with the synchronization.  However, is there really synchronization, since you're apparently passing a nil pointer rather than an object to `@synchronized`?

Comment: @HotLicks: Oops!!! That seems to be a very stupid error on my side :-( ! I will try if I find the project again, fix that and update the results.

Comment: @HotLicks: How embarrassing! But thank you for the feedback, I have updated the answer.

Comment: There may well be a way to do multi-threading where you accumulate the "local" mimima/maxima within each thread and then synchronize once at the end.  But it would be considerably more complex.  (Always be suspicious when "parallel" is faster than single-threaded.)

Answer (score 14):

Save float by wrapping under NSNumber then

```
NSNumber *max=[numberArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"];
NSNumber *min=[numberArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.doubleValue"];
```

**Not compiled and checked, already checked with intValue, not sure about double or float*

Answer (score 2):

sort it. take the first and the last element.

btw: you cant store floats in an NSArray, you will need to wrap them in NSNumber objects.

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@2.1, @8.1, @5.0, @.3];
numbers = [numbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

float min = [numbers[0] floatValue];
float max = [[numbers lastObject] floatValue];
```

Comment: Not performant. Enumerating through each object is a much better solution

Comment: we cannot assume performance here as the actual sorting algorithm and also the datastore of an array is hidden from the user. but if yu want to provide test data I am happy to incorporate it into my answer.

Comment: What is the Big-O notation for enumerating through items in an array once? it's n. Find me a sort algorithm that can have an O notation of n in a case where it's not sorted. The only way it can perform as well is if all items in array are already sorted, which in that case this question wouldn't exist http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: what is the point of micro-optimizing code in GUI apps? your neurons will always be slower. and actually you are assuming that NSArrays are lists. they are not. http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sorting the array then picking the first and last elements, but I find this solution more elegant (this will also work for non numeric objects by changing the comparison inside the block):

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = @[@(3), @(5), @(1)];
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *item1 = (NSNumber *)obj1;
    NSNumber *item2 = (NSNumber *)obj2;
    return [item1 compare:item2];
}];
```

If you really want to get fancy and have a really long list and you don't want to block your main thread, this should work:

```
 NSComparator comparison = ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *item1 = (NSNumber *)obj1;
    NSNumber *item2 = (NSNumber *)obj2;
    return [item1 compare:item2];
};

void(^asychSort)(void) = ^
{
    NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:comparison];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Finished Sorting");
        //do your callback here
    });
};

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), asychSort);
```

Comment: note that my solution will also work for non numeric objects.

Comment: to clarify: the `compare:` method is not limited to "numeric objects", it is the duty of the objects themselves to implement it. So although you gave a impressive answer, it is not correct.

Comment: I am confused. Did I say compare is only limited to numeric objects? Is there actually an error in the code I posted, if so, please point it out.

Comment: you find your solution more elegant, as it works with non numeric objects as-well. this implies, the other doesn't.

Comment: Nope, I like it because it uses blocks and I love me some blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Made simple

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@2.1, @8.1, @5.0, @.3];
numbers = [numbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

float min = [numbers[0] floatValue];
float max = [[numbers lastObject] floatValue];

NSLog(@"MIN%f",min);
NSLog(@"MAX%f",max);
```

Comment: Where is the difference to http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931145/1187415?