# min and max of NSArray without Zeros

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a NSArray and want to know the maximum and min integers.

I currently use:

```
int max = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
int min = [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"] intValue];
```

but now I want to know the minimum and maximum without the zeros entering (arrays only have positive values​​)

```
ex:
array=[3, 6 ,7 , 13, 86, 45, 0]
min=3
max=86
```

Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want a function to return the max integer in your array ?

Comment: I  can not understand your question .. can you elaborate more ?

Comment: for maximum I have, I want one that returns this value without counting the zeros

Comment: do you mean in your case 3 is the min, ignoring 0 which is smaller ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD is just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int xmin = INTMAX_MAX;
for (NSNumber *num in numbers) {
    int x = num.intValue;
    if (x < xmin && x!= 0) xmin = x;
}
```

Comment: For an `int`, use `INT_MAX`. (That reminds me of the code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931719/1187415 :-)

Comment: Hey, no fair actually writing code!!  (Never mind that it's faster than using KVC and easier to understand.)

Comment: Yep, slightly modified to not include zeros =)

Comment: (And it would make sense to throw in the max as well, rather than continue to use KVC for that.)