# How to find the smallest and biggest object of an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am trying to make it so that I can find and log the biggest object of an NSMutableArray. I have searched for this, but I have only seen it for an NSArray. This is the code I saw.

```
numbers = [numbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

float min = [numbers[0] floatValue]
float max = [[numbers lastObject] floatValue];
```

However, when I put that in, it doesn't work because I am using a mutable array. 
Thanks!

Comment: It should work just fine for a mutable array.  However, it's an inefficient way to perform that task, if you don't need the array sorted for any other reason.  Sort is O(n log n), but the function can be performed O(n) with a simple loop and two compare operations.

Comment: Just do `[numbers sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];`. This will sort `numbers` in place.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931112/finding-the-smallest-and-biggest-value-in-nsarray-of-nsnumbers.

Answer (score 3):

It works for mutable array.

```
NSArray *sortedNumbers = [numbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

float min = [sortedNumbers[0] floatValue]
float max = [[sortedNumbers lastObject] floatValue];
```

Comment: Just sort the mutable array in place. No need for the new array.

Comment: Thanks guys rmaddy gave me the answer. I just used [myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; and then displayed the [myArray lastObject] to display the best score. Again Thanks!